# Django pagination on a model with foreignkey

Tags: python, django, pagination

I have two django models `Calculations` and `Customers`. The Calculations model has user as ForeignKey, but the user can be empty.

The view is as follows :

```
def archive(request):        
    calculations = Calculations.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    calculation_data = []
    for calculation in calculations:
        customer_fullname, car_chassis, car_registration = ('', '', '')
        if calculation.customer_id is not None:
            customer = Customer.objects.get(id=calculation.customer_id)
            customer_fullname = '{} {}'.format(customer.firstname, customer.lastname)
            car_chassis = customer.chassis
            car_registration = customer.registration

        calculation_data.append({
            'calculation': calculation,
            'price': price_incl_vat(calculation.purchase_price),
            'customer_fullname': customer_fullname,
            'car_chassis': car_chassis,
            'car_registration': car_registration,
        })
    context = {'calculation_data': calculation_data}
    return render(request, 'master/archive.html', context)
```

And in `archive.html` I loop through `calculation_data` as follows :

```
{% for calculation in calculation_data %}
.....
.....
{% endif %}
```

And everything works fine.

Now I want to implement pagination.

According to docs it can be done as :

```
calculations = Calculations.objects.all()
paginator = Paginator(calculations, 25)
```

But how can I implement pagination to my `calculation_data`? Because there is stored all the data through which I loop in the template.

Of is there an better way to write the query to be able to accomplish pagination?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/pagination/) you can pass a list to Paginator so you can do the same with calculation_data:

```
>>> from django.core.paginator import Paginator
>>> objects = ['john', 'paul', 'george', 'ringo']
>>> p = Paginator(objects, 2)
```